# Opening workspace as a tab in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, adobe-photoshop-elements

When I create a new file in Photoshop CS6, it's something like on the left part of the picture below. What should I do so the result of opening/creating file will open it in the size of the entire window, but not in some small separated window?

[image: my_picture]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navigate to `Photoshop CC > Preferences > Workspace...` and tick the **Open Documents as Tabs** box:

[image]

Comment: Photoshop SC6: Edit -> Preferences -> Interface -> Open Documents as Tabs